# Using PTZ Optics 20x-IP with BlackMagic ATEM Studio 4k

Tags: production, video-standards

Does anyone have experience using PTZ Optics (20x-IP) cameras with the Black Magic ATEM (Studio 4k)? I can get video on a television and over IP, but for some reason I can't get it to show at all on the Black Magic ATEM switcher.

I'm running video through SDI onto Cat6 cable. Is there any chance that something about the signal would work on a TV but not on the video switcher?

Answer (score 1):

Robert,

I too am thinking about buying this camera to use with my ATEM switcher. The ATEM can be quite finicky regarding compatibility. Have you tried it with straight SDI into the ATEM? If this does not work try adding a cheap sdi splitter from Kanex etc to the line.

The camera needs to be set to the exact right settings to work, for example 1080i. The PTX Optics manual says that "After changing the switch, you need to restart the camera to take effect"

You can check the compatibility of your Cat 6 conversion equipment at [atemuser forum](http://www.atemuser.com/CompatibleEquipment)

and share your results.

Comment: I've also heard that the ATEM can only work with one kind of signal at a time, so if you have more than one camera plugged into it, they all need to be sending the same type of signal (eg, 1080i).  I don't have one, so I can't personally verify.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of problem-solving and testing of different combinations (including two versions of black magic video switchers, the studio 4K, and the television studio), I got rid of the black magic. it was the best decision I made in a month. It turns out that this is a very common problem with the black magic, along with constant software crashing.
Now I'm using black magic ultra studio video encoders and they work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The ATEM works with 29.98 fps. The PTX Optics camera is 30fps. You need one of this in between to fix the fps issue. http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=1091826&gclid=COm6mIXnicgCFdgLgQodNIACbQ&is=REG&m=Y&Q=&A=details